# JQuery Plugins, include in Ionic 2 project

Tags: ionic-framework

'm not planning on using JQuery much at all in my new Ionic 2 app.

However I do need to include the Datatables JQuery plugin, as I'm looking for a consistent UI across platforms.

Datatables is available on npm, as separate js and css packages.

I don't have any clue about how to start including the plugin in my app and then initialising the datatables, which I would normally do with $(.table).datatable();

Has anyone done this? Could give me any pointers in this 101 question...

Tom